# Squid client purge utility

Tags: squid

I've been using the purge utility ie.

squidclient -m PURGE http://www.mysite.com/

The above command will purge that exact link but it leaves everything else under it in the cache. (eghttp://www.mysite.com/page1)

I was wondering is there a way to purge every document under that url?

Thanks in Advance Ruth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd-party [purge](http://www.wa.apana.org.au/~dean/squidpurge) utility will do exactly what you seek:

> The purge tool is a kind of magnifying
>   glass into your squid-2 cache. You can
>   use purge to have a look at what URLs
>   are stored in which file within your
>   cache. The purge tool can also be used
>   to release objects which URLs match
>   user specified regular expressions. A
>   more troublesome feature is the
>   ability to remove files squid does not
>   seem to know about any longer.

For our accelerating (reverse) proxy, I use a config like this:

```
purge -c /etc/squid/squid.conf -p localhost:80 -P0 -se 'http://www.mysite.com/'
```

-P0 will show the list of URLs but not remove them; change it to -P1 to send PURGE to the cache, as you do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

We have a lot of ways to purge. Example 2 ways I alway use:

With client using MacOS or Linux:

```
curl -X PURGE http://URL.of.Site/ABC.txt
```

Direct on server which is running Squid:

```
squidclient -m PURGE http://URL.of.Site/ABC.txt
```

Absolutely, squid.conf must add

```
acl Purge method PURGE
http_access allow localhost Purge
http_access allow localnet Purge
http_access deny Purge
```